# Fetching api data in one file and use in another component

Tags: reactjs

I fetch data from api like this

```
import axios from 'axios'

const baseUrl = `${process.env.REACT_APP_URL}/search/users?q=john&per_page=5`

export function fetchData(){
    axios({
          method: "get",
          headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
          url: baseUrl,
        })
          .then(function (response) {
            return response.data;
            
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            return error;
            
          })
          
    }
```

and called to another file

```
import {fetchData} from '../../api/service'

 const dataVal =  fetchData()
  console.log("data",dataVal)
```

got undefined in console

I am expecting to get array data from the api

Comment: The is no `return` in the function

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a `return` like this:

```
export function fetchData() {
  return axios({
    method: "get",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    url: baseUrl,
  })
    .then(function (response) {
      return response.data;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      return error;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You need to update your code like this**

Page 1)

```
import axios from 'axios'
    
    const baseUrl = `${process.env.REACT_APP_URL}/search/users?q=john&per_page=5`
    
    export  function fetchData(){
       return axios({
              method: "get",
              headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
              url: baseUrl,
            })
              .then( (response) => response.data
                
              )
              .catch( (error)=> 
                error
                
              )
              
        }
```

Page 2)

```
import {fetchData} from '../../api/service'

 fetchData().then(res=>{console.log("data",res})
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, The result undefined is expected because you are not returning anything from the fetch Data method. Make your fetch Data as async function and await at axios. Declare a variable and assign response data in first then , Return the variable now you can able to get the required result.

```js
import axios from 'axios'

const baseUrl = `${process.env.REACT_APP_URL}/search/users?q=john&per_page=5`

export async function fetchData(){
     let data;
    await axios({
          method: "get",
          headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
          url: baseUrl,
        })
          .then(function (response) {
            data=response.data;
            
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            return error;
            
          })
          return data
    }
```